# Gracefully handle AWS ECS stop task with .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ecs

I wrote a .NET core console application to run as a task in AWS ECS Fargate.  Basically, the console application starts a processing thread and then needs to just keep running (much like a Kestrel web host.)

Initially, I drop in a Console.ReadKey() thinking it will never hit and the app will keep running.  Well that leads to .NET exception...

```
Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console 
or when console input has been redirected. Try Console.Read.
```

So I then replace ReadKey with Console.Read().  The application acts like it isn't even there, keeps on moving, and the app exits as soon as it starts.

Through research, I discover the Console.CancelKeyPress event.  I implement that, and it works in the fact that the console app will keep running.

```
ManualResetEvent _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eArgs) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down.");
                _quitEvent.Set();
                eArgs.Cancel = true;
            };
_quitEvent.WaitOne();
```

But I would like to gracefully handle shutdown of the application when that does occur.

Through additional research, I find that when AWS ECS stops a task, it doesn't send Ctrl-C (SIGINT) it instead will send SIGTERM.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/stop-task.html

I then implement what I think is the standard event handling for SIGTERM in .NET (seen below.)

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ctx =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down.");
                _quitEvent.Set();
            };
_quitEvent.WaitOne();
```

This compiles and runs fine in ECS.  BUT... I hit the "stop" button through AWS ECS console, it stops the task and relaunches a new task.  When I look at the log of that stopped task, there is no shutdown log message, no indication of a graceful shutdown, nothing.  It appears that it was just force killed.

Am I missing something here?  What can I do differently to gracefully catch the stop-task in AWS ECS to gracefully shut down the task?

Comment: The `docker stop` command attempts to stop a running container first by sending a SIGTERM signal to the root process (PID 1) in the container. Question. Is your .NET Core app is running as root process within container?. If you can please share your sample code repo where we can try to replicate the behavior, it will help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it has do with your .net code of handling graceful shutdown. I just tested with following code locally, with docker and with ECS Stop-Task. At all places, I received graceful shutdown. I don't have your full code so I created my own example.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using System.Threading;

namespace consoleapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _quitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Unloading += ctx =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Unloding fired");
                _quitEvent.Set();
            };
            System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for signals");
            _quitEvent.WaitOne();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Received signal gracefully shutting down");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Full github repo reference if you want to try by yourself.
https://github.com/imran9m/netconsoleapp.git

Sample Logs you should see for container.

> Waiting for signals
>
> Unloding fired
>
> Received signal gracefully shutting down
>
> Hello World!

Note - To test SIGTERM signal locally, you will need to run `kill -SIGTERM {PID}` instead of CTRL+C on dotnet CLI.